# Why is this *not* off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

Consider this: [Non-public API usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369633/non-public-api-usage)

According to the question the problem has nothing to do with the OP's code. All answers (so far) have nothing to do with code.

So how can this not be off-topic?

Comment: Do you mean to assert it is off-topic **because** "the problem has nothing to do with the OP's code" and "all answers [...] has [sic] nothing to do with code"? I'm not familiar with the tech there but is that question not about how to use a tool commonly used by programmers?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve programming or programming tools**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

The question covers a software tool commonly used by programmers, and it's a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. So it's on-topic.

Comment: I see, I was a bit too focused at the first two bullet points. Thank you!